# OpenLayers 3 - use MultiLineString in geometryFunction of Custom Draw Interaction

Tags: javascript, svg, openlayers-3, multilinestring

I'm working with the OL3 example [DrawShapes](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-shapes.html). There is a "star" as example for a custom draw interaction with a user defined geometry function looking like

```
   draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: source,
        type:  'Circle',
        geometryFunction: 
          function(coordinates, geometry) {
            if (!geometry) {
              geometry = new ol.geom.Polygon(null);
            }

            //Calculate coordinates and set geometry

          }
   });
```

What I am actually trying to achieve is replacing this geometry with a custom SVG. The user should be able to draw these SVGs (basically arrows) with the circle-like two point interaction, just like in the example.

I already parsed the svg to a OL-MultilineString geometry. But when I am trying to replace the Polygon with my custom MultiLineString, the "basic geometry stroke" from `center` to `last` in the example also appears. Is this intended behavior or not and how can I get rid of this additional line?

Does it make a difference to recreate the geometry every time during the draw interaction or to use deltas and change the geometry continuously?

[star with dispensable line in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qh7T.png)

For testing you can just use the above link and replacing the `ol.geom.Polygon(null)` with a `ol.geom.MultiLineString(null)`

I appreciate every solution including different approaches.

Comment: Having trouble & asking for help is not a question, read [ask] and edit the question.

Comment: I clearly specified the question part, having trouble is usually the way leading to a question, isn't it? I reformatted a bit, now it should be more comprehensible.